# replace garbage characters within mysql

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, latin1

My db is in `latin1` and is full of `â&quot;` or `'��&quot;'` (depending on whether my terminal is set to latin1 or unicode, respectively). From context, I think they should be emdashes.  They appear to be causing nasty bugs when rendered (or not rendered) in IE.  I'd like to find and replace them.  The problem is that neither the â nor � character match with `replace`.  Running the query:

```
    update TABLE set COLUMN = replace(COLUMN,'��&quot;','---');
```

Executes without error but doesn't do anything (0 rows changed).  It's clear to me that the "question mark in the diamond" character is not being matched when I copy it in the terminal.  Is there a way to find out its code and match it by that or something?  The `mysql` console is tantalizingly close to being able to do this in one line so I'd rather not script it outside the terminal if I can avoid it.

The db is hosted Amazon RDS so I can't install the regexp udf that I've seen referenced in other questions here. In the long term, I'm going to have to properly convert the whole db to utf8 but I need to fix this rendering problem right away.

EDIT:

I've isolated the bad character with `hexdump`, it's e2 80 (I don't think this corresponds to any unicode character).  How can I feed that to the replace function?

```
    update TABLE set COLUMN = replace(COLUMN, char(0xe2,0x80),'---');
```

does not do anything.

Comment: Is there a reason for it to be latin1? I tend to use unicode by default now and it's not that hard to convert - just dump the DB to SQL, and reload it into a new one that uses utf8.

Comment: I inherited it.  A dump is undesirable because it would entail significant downtime which I would like to avoid.  I've been reading up on in-place methods like http://nicj.net/2011/04/17/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8 but haven't had time to adapt it to my db.

Comment: You may have no other choice but to find all rows with this faulty character sequence and hand-craft individual statements to fix each one (a script can help do this, though).

Comment: Is the data stored incorrectly, displayed incorrectly, or really broken? Please have a look at the database section of http://kunststube.net/frontback/ and try to figure that out. The answer may be to export the data in the "wrong" encoding and reimport it back in the correct encoding.

Comment: All of the above in this particular case.  In general, we're storing good UTF8 in latin1 columns and then pulling it out and rendering it as UTF8 so things work smoothly.  The second something isn't right, though...it gets very hard to manage.  I'll be converting everything to UTF8 in the db shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I used mysql's builtin `hex` function to dump an entry that I knew was bad.

```
    select hex(column) from table where id=666;
```

Then picked out the words (those numbers sandwiched between "20"s) and discovered that my offending  set of bytes was in fact `x'C3A2E282AC2671756F743B'`.  How this corresponds to the way I saw it encoded in PHP and by my system (as `e2 80`) I don't know and at this point, I don't really care.

To verify, before destroying the data, you plug that back in to mysql:

```
    select x'C3A2E282AC2671756F743B';
    +---------------------------+
    | x'C3A2E282AC2671756F743B' |
    +---------------------------+
    | â€&quot;               |
    +---------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, using the replace query like above, I was able to get rid of all the bad data at once.

For the record it was:

```
    update TABLE set COLUMN = replace(COLUMN, x'C3A2E282AC2671756F743B','--');
```

I really hope this is useful for someone.  Though encoding snafus appear to be pretty common in mysql, I searched *everywhere* and I couldn't find an explanation for this ultimately rather simple process.

Comment: `x'C3A2'` is UTF-8 for `â`; `x'E282AC'` is UTF-8 for `€`; `x'2671756F743B'` is ASCII for `&quot;` so something is doing Unicode encoding...

Comment: @Neil I think the story was that the text was prepared with some MS cp1252 (or a different MS scheme??) then ineffectively converted to UTF8 and dumped in a latin1 column.  The cp1252 en/em dash does not copy nicely to UTF8 so whatever was converting it turned it in to what appears to be arbitrary junk... But en(em)dash is 96(97) in cp1252 and E2 80 93 (E2 80 94) in UTF8...not sure how either of those became c3a2e82ac...

Comment: E2 80 94 is `â€”` in Windows-1252 - perhaps the smart quote got turned into a `&quot;` somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

Something might have submitted the em dash (U+2014) with UTF-8 encoding (E2 80 94), which you are now trying to interpret as latin-1, however this is not valid in latin-1 which excludes the range 80-9F so you probably see Unicode replacement characters for the illegal bytes instead, thus resulting in `â��` when you display it. By comparison in Windows-1252 it would display as `â€”`.

You may be able to use `CHAR(0xE2, 0x80, 0x94)` to create the search string.

Comment: Your answer led me in the right direction, I've figured out that the bad character is `e2 80` .  But how do I form the replace query? it's not how I would have expected it to be.

Comment: Actually...it's not e2 80.  See my resolution of the problem below.